# Azure File Share - Custom URL/file

Tags: azure, cloud

Hi Serverfault community,

Does Azure's File Share provide an individual URL for each file I place on "transfer area"? Is it possible to grant permission to individual files but deny the final user to list folder's files?

I'm starting to use Azure, I want to migrate our current local file share server which's an IIS Directory to the cloud. Is it a coherent decision?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, azure files is all or nothing, azure file sync might be what you are looking for: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-active-directory-overview

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to copy on premises shared IIS directory for hosting in Azure and trying to access those files using URL, in that case the best solution will be to use Azure VM with windows & IIS image and copy your folder to that VM and host in the IIS similar to on premises.